# OpenShift Running WordPress with ManageWP

Tags: wordpress, openshift

I just installed WordPress on Openshift about a month ago. I also added a plugin called ManageWP Worker Plugin. But, the sites I manage on OpenShift, ManageWP can't connect to. But,  my sites hosted on other webhosts connect to ManageWP without any problems.

I have contacted the ManageWP Support team, and they said that it was a server issue on your side. If there anything I can do to get the plugin working?

Error Message:

“Latest ManageWP Worker plugin version not detected. Install/update ManageWP Worker plugin on your website.”

Anything I can do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect the managewp site to a wordpress blog on OpenShift Online without issue.  What url did you use when you added your site to the managewp service?  I just used the app-domain.rhcloud.com one.  Also make sure that you activated the managewp plugin after installing it.